# How can I schedule more than one functions to get executed at different time frame in Python forever

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3x, how can I repeatedly execute more than one functions in Python forever?

For instance, I have two function, *'funcA'* and *'funcB'*. I want *'funcA'* to get executed every 17 seconds while *'funcB'* will be execute every 13 seconds.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an infinite while loop and keep a count of the second, using `time.sleep()` to pause:

```
import time

t = 0
while True:
    t += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if t % 13 == 0:
        funcB()
    if t % 17 == 0:
        funcA()
```

You can also use `itertools.count()` with a `for` loop instead of an infinite `while`:

```
import itertools
import time

for i in itertools.count(1):
    time.sleep(1)
    if i % 13 == 0:
        funcB()
    if i % 17 == 0:
        funcA()
```